# Hi, I was trying to include an external libray (liblcd.a) in my eclipse project. I tried to follow these steps

Tags: eclipse

1) in Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Compiler >> Includes you must add the include path for the external library (where the header reside). This information is needed by the Eclipse indexer (code completion etc.) and the compiler

2) Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries you must add the library search path (option -L) and the library you want to link against (option -l). This info is needed for the linker.

The two above, but I get this error. Could it be because I am saving the library file as a notepad file? Could someone please help ? Thank you :)

This is the error
c:/winavr-20100110/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.3/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/aì\l /Desktop/New\ directory\ (2)/liblcd.a
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1

Comment: Many things could happen in your environment, too many variable elements to give specific hint. Have you tried to follow receipts from other forums like this? http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/404845#comment-404845

Comment: Does you path contains some non-ascii characters? Your user name looks weird, the "i" with comma instead of dot. This can make path illegal for linker.